# WCF webservice running on a two server cluster, with loadbalancer, resolving web service address

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, load-balancing

Apologies for the long winded title but looking for a solution to what might be a common problem.

We have a loadbalancer with address, say:  `www.myloadbalancer.com`

Below are two web servers

First server: `webserver1.farm.com`
Second server: `webserver2.farm.com`

We deployed a webservice on to the two servers but noticed something funny when trying to consume the web services somewhere else.

We deploy to:

- `webserver1.farm.com/service1.svc` and
- `webserver2.farm.com/service1.svc`

Because the web servers are not directly accessible online you have to go through the load balancer.

So the address to consume is `www.myloadbalancer.com/service1.svc`.

However what we are finding is that if the loadbalancer directs you to server 1, and you check the WSDL, you see the service name and details as `webserver1.farm.com/service1.svc` not `www.myloadbalancer.com/service1.svc`.

If you attempt to consume `www.myloadbalancer.com/service1.svc`, say in Visual Studio 2008, you get a warning that `webserver1.farm.com/service1.svc` does not exist.

The main question is, is it possible to give an alias name to a webservice.
in other words is it possible to get the service to describe itself as  `www.myloadbalancer.com/service1.svc` regardless of whether we end up on web server 1 or 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A WSDL file is a WSDL file. Edit it to point to the correct URL. (You don't have to use the auto-generated http://webserver1.farm.com/service1.svc?WSDL if you don't want to.)

Comment: This tutorial may explain it? http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/kirillg/archive/2006/06/18/28380.aspx